# How to choose the location for the local repository for Mylyn tasks?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, mylyn

I am using a local repository for Mylyn. I would like to save the repository as file in the version controlled path for my project. This way I can have backup and versioning for my tasks. How can I set the repository path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Windows / Prferences / Tasks
- Open up hidden fieldgroup under "Advanced"
- PROFIT

Comment: Yes, it works, but it has lots of files I don't want in my repository

Comment: Then try another solution -- to repository, but some simple daily backup of the whole folder somewhere.

Comment: As I see them, you seems, will have not a very good versioning with *.zip files, until you have some git (if you use it) hacks to understand, that *.zip on concrete location should be unzipped before comparing.

Comment: I guess I can setup a cron job to unzip and copy the tasks from the Mylyn folder to my project's versioned folder.